# Overlay three histograms in one plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to plot something like this using data from a `Pandas DataFrame`. The date are numbers between 0 and 100 representing percentages. I have 3 columns representing 3 different categories with percentages values for each.

What I would like to get:

[image: perfect hist example]

What I get using this code:

```
df_margins = pd.read_excel("path to excel file")
df_margins.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df_margins_sort = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df_margins.values, axis=0), index=df_margins.index, columns=df_margins.columns)
df_margins_sort.hist( alpha=0.5)
```

[image: result 1]

Trying with `seaborn` library I get this:

```
x = df_margins_sort["safety_margin_distribution_0"].tolist()
y = df_margins_sort["safety_margin_distribution_5"].tolist()
z = df_margins_sort["safety_margin_distribution_10"].tolist()
ggg = [x,y,z]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for a in ggg:
    sns.distplot(a, bins=range(1, 100, 10), ax=ax, kde=False)
ax.set_xlim([0, 100])
```

[image: seaborn results]

A screenshot of my data that I am trying to plot:
[image: data example]

```
79.6657 8.3008  12.0334
28  72  0       
51.4077 48.5923 0
84.1176 2.7451  13.1373
79.5455 1.0101  19.4444
51.9205 48.0795 0
57.2877 6.5906  36.1217
71.2589 11.4014 17.3397
56.2624 43.7376 0
76.4228 0   23.5772
51.8473 6.6502  41.5025
74.8555 25.1445 0
85.8254 14.1746 0
63.2754 0.7444  35.9801
```

Comment: Please include your data as text.

Comment: @QuangHoang added data as text.

Comment: what's wrong with the second plot?

Comment: @PaulH in the second plot it looks that I have more than 3 categories. also, I would like to avoid using seaborn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/):

#### Your Data:

```py
 safety_margin_distribution_5  safety_margin_distribution_10  safety_margin_distribution_0
                      79.6657                         8.3008                       12.0334
                      28.0000                        72.0000                        0.0000
                      51.4077                        48.5923                        0.0000
                      84.1176                         2.7451                       13.1373
                      79.5455                         1.0101                       19.4444
                      51.9205                        48.0795                        0.0000
                      57.2877                         6.5906                       36.1217
                      71.2589                        11.4014                       17.3397
                      56.2624                        43.7376                        0.0000
                      76.4228                         0.0000                       23.5772
                      51.8473                         6.6502                       41.5025
                      74.8555                        25.1445                        0.0000
                      85.8254                        14.1746                        0.0000
                      63.2754                         0.7444                       35.9801
```

#### Code

- [`seaborn.distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html)
- The key issue with the original attempt using `seaborn`, was not providing a `label` and not calling `plt.legend()`
- It is not necessary to create a separate object for each column, as done with `[x, y, z]`

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplt as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(7, 6))
for col in df.columns:
    sns.distplot(df[col], label=col,
                 bins=range(0, 101, 10),
                 kde=False, hist_kws=dict(edgecolor='black'))

plt.xlabel('Value Range')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.legend()
plt.xticks(range(0, 101, 10))
plt.show()
```

[image]

- The `bins` parameter of `distplot`, sets the bin sizes, but to enforce labels on the tick marks, use `plt.xticks`

Comment: This seems a lot like the OP's existing plot. What's different about it, other than figure aesthetics?

Comment: @PaulH The first plot shown by the OP is "**What I'd Like to Get**".  The OP wanted, but was not able to produce the first plot.  Additionally, the OP first saved each column to a list, then tried to plot it.  This answer properly uses seaborn and produces the desired plot, specifically as the OP requested.

Comment: But what's the issue with the second plot? The aesthetics or the numeric results of the histogram computation? To clarify -- by "second plot" I mean the OP's second attempt at producing the "what I'd like to get" plot

Comment: @PaulH I think the OP just didn't use `label` and `plt.legend()` and the dataframe columns were unnecessarily assigned to new objects.

Comment: @Trenton_M thank you very much. the issue with my seaborn plot is that it looks very unintelligible and I didn't know how to edit it to actually check whether it does what I want. at first sight it looks like I plotted multiple categories.

Comment: I completely agree it was unnecessary to create a separate object for each column but I didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try plotting individual hist into the same axis:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(100,3)), columns=list('abc'))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for col in df.columns:
    df[col].hist(alpha=0.3, ax=ax, label=col)

ax.legend()
```

Output, which, by the way, looks like your seaborn output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose a different approach. It doesn't avoid seaborn, but it does avoid loops.

The work flow is there: read in the data, convert to a tidy (long) format, and then map the histogram to a seaborn Facet Grid:

from io import StringIO
import pandas
import seaborn

seaborn.set(style='ticks')

```py
data = StringIO("""\
safety_margin_distribution_5  safety_margin_distribution_10  safety_margin_distribution_0
                      79.6657                         8.3008                       12.0334
                      28.0000                        72.0000                        0.0000
                      51.4077                        48.5923                        0.0000
                      84.1176                         2.7451                       13.1373
                      79.5455                         1.0101                       19.4444
                      51.9205                        48.0795                        0.0000
                      57.2877                         6.5906                       36.1217
                      71.2589                        11.4014                       17.3397
                      56.2624                        43.7376                        0.0000
                      76.4228                         0.0000                       23.5772
                      51.8473                         6.6502                       41.5025
                      74.8555                        25.1445                        0.0000
                      85.8254                        14.1746                        0.0000
                      63.2754                         0.7444                       35.9801
""")

df = (
    pandas.read_csv(data, sep='\s+')
        .stack()
        .to_frame('Safety Margin')
        .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
        .assign(Distribution=lambda df: df.index.str.rsplit('_', 1).map(lambda x: int(x[-1])))
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .pipe((seaborn.FacetGrid, 'data'), hue='Distribution', size=5)
        .map(seaborn.distplot, 'Safety Margin', kde=False, bins=range(0, 100, 5))
        .add_legend()
)
```

I'm not saying this is better than the loop-based answers. But there can be advantages to working with tidy data and mapping across a facet grid (for instance, if you decide to split the plot further into rows and columns)